# Генерация случайной ASCII строки

Tags: python

Генерирую ASCII-строку следующим образом:

```
def buildblock(size):
    out_str = ''
    for i in range(0, size):
        a = random.randint(65,90)
        out_str += chr(a)
    return(out_str)
```

Но в таком случае генерируются символы только верхнего регистра. Например, *FGLKJDSDH*. А как сделать так, чтобы генерировались строки и нижнего и верхнего регистра одновременно? По типу *YjhmrdVDgm*

Comment: Похожая задача с быстрым решением: [Fastest method to generate big random string with lower Latin letters](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16308989/4279)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
import random
import string

def buildblock(size):
    return ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for _ in range(size))
```

Можно добавить ещё и цифры:

```
import random
import string

def buildblock(size):
    return ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits) for _ in range(size))
```

[Действующий код](https://repl.it/Cz6E/0)

Answer (score 1):

```
from random import choice

from string import ascii_letters

print(''.join(choice(ascii_letters) for i in range(12)))
```

Comment: Чем ваш ответ принципиально отличается от уже имеющегося?

Comment: более короткая запись

Comment: Не думаю, что это отличие настолько принципиально, что обязательно требуется создавать новый ответ